# Installed Ubuntu. Cant log into Windows

Tags: boot, windows

A few days ago, I installed Ubuntu on my HP desktop and followed all the directions. I intended to have a dual boot computer with Ubuntu and Windows.
After all that hardwork , I am unable to log into windows in the grub menu. I see a message that says "Can't find command drivemap" "Invalid EFI file path."

I tried a lot of options found on ubuntu forums on the internet.

I can confirm that when I was installing Ubuntu, I created the partitons on the largest available free space on the disk ( 930 MB). I am unsure if that contributed to the issue. The installations instructions did indeed say to pick a large free space. I can also confirm that I might have gotten confused while creating the EFI. Now I see /EFI and boot/efi. I am unsure if I there are supposed to be 2 EFI partitions. The link below will show you the screenshot with the 2 EFIs.

I am kinda fed up now.

Can some one please tell me how I can just recover all my windows files and programs?

I dont care about reinstalling/ recovering windows. I can just buy a new computer.
I dont care about reinstalling/ recovering Ubuntu.
I dont care about recovering and Ubuntu files either.

All I care about is recovering my windows files and programs.

I appreciate your time and effort.

JB

https://ibb.co/k55WjBH

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your attached screenshot, I think you might have wiped away Windows when you installed Ubuntu... If that's the case, I would suggest unplugging your harddisk from the desktop and taking it to the nearest data recovery company. But just to verify it's not the case (fingers crossed), can you post the output of `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`? (That's a lower "L", not the number one)

Comment: Here is the ouput of that command. Ty

https://ibb.co/qJSCDkv

Comment: Yeah, sadly it was completely wiped. The code (8300 vs EF00) shows that `/boot/efi` is the real EFI partition, not `/EFI`.
If you want to try to recover the data yourself, there are several different commercial programs you can use. Try searching for "data recovery software" on your favorite search engine. I've had bad experience with the freebie ones though. Good luck!

Comment: Ok. Ty for the feedback. I just ordered a USB to harddisk adapter to retrive as much info as possible. I will make a small donation, in your honor, to St.Judes Children's Cancer hospital for the effort you put in to help me out.

Comment: WYPHAN:

I just gave them $5 in your honor. Here is the link to the receipt. Thanks again, be well!

https://ibb.co/WcyyBdG